# My value does not set correctly in TcSetInterface

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn

In [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374462(v=vs.85).aspx) is written:

> Using `TcSetInterface`. Set `GUID_QOS_FLOW_MODE` to
>   `ADAPTER_FLOW_MODE_DIFFSERV`

So I wrote my code like this:

```
auto guid = GUID_QOS_FLOW_MODE;
ULONG mode = ADAPTER_FLOW_MODE_DIFFSERV;
auto err = TcSetInterface(interface_handle, &guid, sizeof(mode), &mode);
```

It returns zero which means no error. But when I try to check if it is set correctly or not using this code:

```
ULONG bufferSize = sizeof(ULONG);           
err = TcQueryInterface(interface_handle, &guid, false, &bufferSize, &mode);
```

It sets `mode` to zero instead of 1.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: how about look for `GetLastError` after `TcSetInterface` fail ?

Comment: @RbMm it returns zero.

Comment: @RbMm: [TcSetInterface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374460.aspx) doesn't set the last error code. Calling `GetLastError` produces a meaningless value.

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, my mistake